# Not able to display a label after downloading a file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a button in my `asp.net` project, upon clicking an excel sheet gets downloaded, I also want to display the `MD5 hash` code of the file. The application is working fine but the label is not getting displayed but while debugging, hash code is getting generated and it is also  successfully assigned to the label but it is not getting displayed in the front end.

Please help me resolve this. My code looks like this.

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    pnlHashCode.Visible = true;
    lblHashCode.Visible = true;

    string strURL = "UploadHONMarks.xls";
    WebClient req = new WebClient();
    pnlHashCode.Visible = true;
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearContent();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.Buffer = true;
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "UploadHONMarks.xls"));
    Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
    response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(strURL));

    string filename = Server.MapPath("UploadHONMarks.xls");
    byte[] hashBytes;
    MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create();
    hashBytes = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filename));
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++) {
        sBuilder.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    pnlHashCode.Visible = true;
    lblHashCode.Text = sBuilder.ToString();

}
```

Comment: Are you setting lblHashCode.Visible = false in other places in code? especially, page load event?

Comment: yup.. in the page load... as I want that label to be invisible at page load. I now understand this is the reason but now please tell me how to resolve it

Comment: In that case, put the 'lblHashCode.Visible = false' under 'not post back' check. So, that the code will not hit during the btnDownload_Click postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending in the same response a Content-Disposition (for file download) and you also want to modify the Web page. That's not possible, because the browser can only process one type of response.

The options are:

- In the response you send a change in the page, **or**
- In the response you send a file for download

The browser does not know how to process two different kind of actions in the same response. In this case the best option is to first send the MD5 hash as an async response, and the link for the download. For example, in sites like sourceforge.net or microsoft.com, when you download a file the site first redirects you to another page, and then it starts downloading. That's because they want to send two messages (the advertise and the download, or the MD5 and the download in your case).

Another option is to send the MD5 in the click response and add a link or button file that's hidden. So, with the MD5 you can trigger a javascript function that makes the "click" event on the link, which download the file. Tricks like these make possible to fake two different actions in the same response.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the answer you provided to my questions, here is my suggestion. Put the
lblHashCode.Visible = false; under !IsPostBack check.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               lblHashCode.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtBatch;
            
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                pnlModule.Visible = false;
                pnlHashCode.Visible = false;
                lblFA.Text = "FA1";
                lblHashCode.Visible = false;

            }

        }